# I can't select "I'm Done" when reviewing

Tags: bug, reviewing

I was looking at the review queue and ended up with a first post review that I had flagged half an hour before for closure. Until recently the "I'm done" choice was available to select if I had previously done something.

Today was different.

I had to select "No Action Needed" when I clearly did something, which feels *wrong*.

[image: Never done with this question]

Comment: I've had this happen before, usually a quick refresh of the page solves it for me